# css animation execute onclick without javascript

Tags: html, css

I'm some kind of new in "css".

I use the code below and It works fine:
but when I move #img6 from #main div to another div It does not work anymore..
It seems that they must be in the same div to work perfectly.

I googled this problem but there were solutions using java script, Is it any other way to put them in different divisions just with css ?

I want to use this code in an asp.net webpage and I need the animation code be executed on click a button in my page.. but I couldn't do that with asp.net button click event either. It seems that my animation code does not executed correctly via asp.net events or methods...

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <label for="toggle-6">I'm a toggle</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-6"/>
  <img id="img6" class="rotated-imag-45-6" src="image/cam.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #img6 {
  transition-duration: 5s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
.rotated-imag-90-6 {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just select a child or a sibling of an element but not a parent. So in another div you can't select anything outside the div nor the div itself.

You have to use JavaScript in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap everything in a wrapper `<div />` and place the checkbox beside it. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z5ssjdw/1/)

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .wrapper #img6 {
  transition-duration: 5s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

This way, once everything is inside the wrapper, it should work

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have a sibling selector in your CSS: `~`

if you 'move' `#img6` to another div, where I can just imagine there isn't a sibling `input[type=checkbox]:checked`, then such selector in your CSS is not matched any more.

if you can't target with an appropriate CSS selector, you will need to use javascript to achieve the same result.