# show and hide a div with transition in CSS without using JavaScript

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to perform transition property to show and hide the div without the involvement of JavaScript. I used the following code:

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(238, 190, 118);
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 230, 0);
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: hide_div 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes hide_div {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hide Div
</div>
```

this is done by animation property. when the given code is executed div is hidden after 5s but there is no way to show it again without refreshing the browser.

Does anyone have an idea how it will be done? let me know, please.

Comment: When do you want it to be shown again? Does the user interact with it or does it come back automatically?

Comment: you can use the input checkbox trick, that give you true or false `:checked` https://stackoverflow.com/a/70590620/17716837

Comment: when user interact with it

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas I want to do it with the transition property not from :checked pseudo-class element

Comment: @BaslaAzhar yes but without Javascript, this is the only way I think that you can trigger a boolean checking (other ways are `:active` for clicking but you if not clicked it will be resetted, instead with input checkbox it will save the true/false value) however sorry if not solved. happy coding!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css animation execute onclick without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893063/css-animation-execute-onclick-without-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to show automatically. Use `alternate infinite` on `animate` css prop.

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(238, 190, 118);
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 230, 0);
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: hide_div 5s alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes hide_div {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hide Div
</div>
```

If you a user to be able to control when the div is shown you could use a checkbox and the next sibling combinator "+" combined with `transition` (rather than animation).

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(238, 190, 118);
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 230, 0);
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

input:checked + div {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<label for="cb">Show The Div</label><input id="cb" type="checkbox">

<div>
  Hide Div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use infinite instead of forwards:

```css
animation: hide_div 5s infinite;
```

That should be enough for your request :)

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(238, 190, 118);
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 230, 0);
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: hide_div 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes hide_div {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hide Div
</div>
```

Comment: No, I want to set it so that when the user interacts with it, it is displayed again.